# Use Three.js PositionalAudio to make a cone of sound

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js

I'm creating an array of sounds with PositionalAudio:

```
 var newVoice = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);
 newVoice.setBuffer(buffer);
 newVoice.setRefDistance(20);
 newVoice.autoplay = true;
 newVoice.setLoop(true);
 voices.push(newVoice);
```

And I've attached these voices to cubes, but I want to only allow the user to hear the sound if they are facing the cube from an angle straight on of 30degress. Anything outside of a 30degree cone should be silent.

I see the [documentation here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/audio/PositionalAudio.js) but the only parameter that is working is the one i used 'setRefDistance.' The others do not work. I'm using r74.

Any ideas? The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/evejweinberg/949e297c34177199386f945549a45c06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three.js Audio is a wrapper for the web audio API. You can apply all the settings to the panner, which is availiable using `getOutput()`:

```
var sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );
var panner = sound.getOutput();
panner.coneInnerAngle = innerAngleInDegrees;
panner.coneOuterAngle = outerAngleInDegrees;
panner.coneOuterGain = outerGainFactor;
```

> **coneInnerAngle**: A parameter for directional audio sources, this is an angle, inside of which there will be no volume reduction. The default value is 360.
>
> **coneOuterAngle**: A parameter for directional audio sources, this is an angle, outside of which the volume will be reduced to a constant value of coneOuterGain. The default value is 360.
>
> **coneOuterGain**: A parameter for directional audio sources, this is the amount of volume reduction outside of the coneOuterAngle. The default value is 0.

Sources:

- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/positional_audio/

Comment: Additionally you should take a moment of your time and read the [stackoverflow-tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about how this site works.

Comment: Thx @Falk Thiele - what specifically should I do differently when I post? Sorry!

Comment: Nothing to worry about, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.